# Is there a way to check a dozen VMs to compare the CPU , RAM and disk storage through VSphere or any other way?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I have been asked to compare the resource usage of VMs in VSphere,. Is there a way to see a grid or something where I don't have to go to every individual VM to compare?

The main thing is we have a third party application that monitors the OS's CPU, RAM and Disk usage but there are discrepancies ( which show much higher usage) as to what the is shown in VSphere. And VSphere seems to show usage way under what is really happening.

Thanks in advance for your help and expertise.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the "third party application"? - What is your real goal?

Comment: Are there discrepancies for all metrics, or only some?

Answer (score 1):

***clicks...***

Seems like it's pretty easy to get an overview of VM consumed space, current CPU MHz, RAM users and such.

[image]

What more are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How I can get a week's worth of info to compare to the Windows Team and what they monitor through the Server logs. And perhaps a way to export the info.